# Damaged sidewall - is this safe or should i replace?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I had a deflating tire. Took it off and found bubble on inner sidewall so decided to replace. Bought one online-used. Had it put on and found sidewall had some rubberized glue on it. Now that the rubber fell off, it looks like this...

[image]

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/2a99lrb.jpg]

Is this safe or should I replace. Tire has about 10K miles left to go on it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hit a curb today, taking a chunk out of the tire and some damage to the rim. Is it still safe to drive?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39492/hit-a-curb-today-taking-a-chunk-out-of-the-tire-and-some-damage-to-the-rim-is)

Comment: I agree that this is a nearly identical question, but due to the nature of the damage, I think each case should be evaluated separately. Since OP provided detailed pictures, I am voting to leave this question open.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Decided to take the advice and replaced with a non repaired tire with same tread as other tires! Figured better safe than sorry. Thank you all again!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the question is "is this safe?" you'll mostly get answers saying that it should be replaced.

That is probably safe to drive, but for safety's sake, I'd replace it. No tire is as safe as a good new tire and personally I won't play around with *"probably"* when it comes to giving advice. I don't want to be responsible for saying something is safe and having it fail soon afterward.

So my answer, replace it at your earliest convenience... but it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

That is a sizeable chunk of sidewall missing, but it should be OK as long as you're not losing air.

I would have the wheel rebalanced if the glue fell off after you had the tire installed on the rim.

Note that tires do have an age limit, so you may not drive it 10,000 miles before it needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that tyre - it seems to be one with the "extra" rubber to protect alloys, so the sidewall thickness may be ok, but you do not know what internal damage may have happened and that can lead to delamination and failure.
I would replace it, but I run 2 sets of tyres and change each set after two seasons for the summer or winter tyres.